# Ошибки при установке npm пакетов

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm

Доброго времени товарищи. Решил попробовать попользоваться npm и установить  tty.js.

Но почему то консолька  начинает ругаться на право и налево. В чем может быть проблема? 
tty.js

```
Сергей@SERGEY C:\Users\Sergey
$ npm install -g tty.js
C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\tty.js -> C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\tty.js\bin\tty.js

> ws@0.4.32 install C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node
_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


Сергей@SERGEY C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node_modul
es\ws
$ if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  e
lse (node "" rebuild )
Построение проектов в этом решении по одному. Чтобы включить параллельную сборку
, добавьте параметр "/m".
C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node_modules\ws\build\b
ufferutil.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: импортированный проект "C:\Microsoft.Cp
p.Default.props" не обнаружен. Проверьте путь в объявлении <Import> и наличие ф
айла на диске.
C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node_modules\ws\build\v
alidation.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: импортированный проект "C:\Microsoft.Cp
p.Default.props" не обнаружен. Проверьте путь в объявлении <Import> и наличие ф
айла на диске.

> pty.js@0.3.1 install C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\n
ode_modules\pty.js
> node-gyp rebuild


Сергей@SERGEY C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node_modul
es\pty.js
$ if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  e
lse (node "" rebuild )
gyp: deps\winpty\winpty.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\tty.js\node_modules\pty.js) while loading dependencies of binding.g
yp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_module
s\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node_module
s\pty.js
gyp ERR! node -v v6.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "tty.js"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! pty.js@0.3.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pty.js@0.3.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pty.js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs pty.js
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pty.js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sergey\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: А питон установлен у вас в системе?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Python version 3.4.3

Comment: Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
python доступен из того места, где вы делаете npm install? путь к бинарнику должен быть в PATH или в переменной PYTHON, как написано в тексте ошибки

Comment: @yurish поставил 2 версию питона и прописал путь. Все те же ошибки но только без ругани на питон.

Comment: @Drop "все те же" это какие? в вопросе выше только одна ошибка про питон. запости новый вывод

Comment: @yurish залил новую ошибку

Comment: @Drop по новой ошибке есть открытый issue на github, проблема в совместимости пакета с виндой, похоже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что пакет tty.js имеет проблемы при установке в windows, см. https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/issues/118